# No me deja avanzar con este codigo

Tags: php, html

Estoy creando una pagina, con mysql, e creado un campo que se llama DNI, pero quiero que los usuarios que no ingresen 8 numeros y una letra mayuscula le salga un error que diga tienes que tienes que introducir 8 numeros y una mayuscula.
Pero no me deja avanzar el codigo que tengo es el siguiente

```
if(!empty($_POST["dni"])!=="[0-9]{8} [A-Z]{1}"){
            echo "Debes Introducir 8 Numeros y una letra mayuscula";``
        }
```

Si introduzco 8 numeros me salta el error, pero si introduzco los 8 numeros y la mayuscula tambien me salta el error y nose como ponerlo para que me salte el error con 9 numeros y no me deje ingresarlo en la base de datos.

Como puedo realizar este ejercicio para que pueda registrarse en la base de datos siendo los 8 numeros y la letra mayuscula

Es que con este codigo aunque ponga el DNI correcto siempre me salta el error y nose ya como ponerlo

Comment: Fíjate que en el patrón hay un espacio, puede que debas quitarlo.

Comment: Esa cláusula `if` está completamente mal. Para empezar, pasito a pasito: ->`!empty($_POST["dni"]) !== "[0-9]{8} [A-Z]{1}"` es igual a `True !== "[0-9]{8} [A-Z]{1}"`, (en caso de que dni no esté vacío, ese será el resultado), y obviamente true nunca va a ser igual a un string raro. Por otro lado, aunque la primera parte no diese un booleano, no está *ejecutando* el patrón, solo comparando si se ha insertado esa cadena... solo daría `true` si el usuario escribe literalmente "[0-9]{8} [A-Z]{1}" en su campo de DNI!

Comment: Ya amigo se que lo tenia mal pero no sabia exactamente como hacerlo, no llevo mucho con programacion llevo poco con esto y lo aprendido como ves es muy poco aun, solo lo estaba utilizando para un proyecto a entregar, de todas maneras muchas gracias me ha servido tu respues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podrías usar [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php) — Realiza una comparación con una expresión regular.

**Un posible ejemplo:**

```
 // DNI
 $dni='26764584Z'; // Tu: $_POST["dni"]
 // Expresión regular  
 $formato=preg_match('/[0-9]{8}[A-Z]{1}$/', $dni);
   
 // Comprobación 
 if ($formato == true) :
    echo 'DNI Valido';
 else :        
     echo 'DNI invalido, escriba 8 digitos y una letra en mayuscula.';
 endif;
```

Ahora si quieres también usar la función `empty`, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
 if(empty($dni) || !preg_match('/[0-9]{8}[A-Z]{1}$/', $dni)) :
    echo 'DNI invalido, escriba 8 digitos y una letra en mayuscula.';
 else:
    echo 'DNI Valido';
 endif;
```

Si lo quieres simplificar, como dice @Benito-B el resultado viene como un `boolean`, es decir es `true` o `false`.

```
 // DNI
 $dni='26764584Z'; // Tu: $_POST["dni"]
 // Expresión regular  
 $formato=preg_match('/[0-9]{8}[A-Z]{1}$/', $dni);
   
 // Comprobación 
 if ($formato) :
    echo 'DNI Valido';
 else :        
     echo 'DNI invalido, escriba 8 digitos y una letra en mayuscula.';
 endif;
```

Ahora, si aún lo quieres optimizar más podrías guardar tu comprobación en una variable y lanzar una respuesta:

```
$validacion = ($formato) ? 'DNI Valido' : 'DNI invalido, escriba 8 digitos y una letra en mayuscula.';
echo $validacion;
```

**Algunos detalles:**

*Expresión regular*: `[0-9]{8}[A-Z]{1}$`

`[]` *permiten agrupar creando rangas*
Por ejemplo `/ad[1-7]+d/`, esta expresión será verdadero con cualquier string que contenga **ad**, un número entre **1** y **7** uno o más veces, y finalmente una **d**.
Un ejemplo verdadero: `$cadena = 'ad13d';`.

`{n}` *operador*
siendo **n** un numero `(int)` positivo, indicamos que el carácter se debe repetir al menos **n** veces.

`$` si coincide con el final de una línea.

Como parte de la notación, siempre encerramos las expresiones regulares entre `/`

Comment: De nada amigo, te he dejado un segundo ejemplo para usarlo con la función `empty`, un saludo.

Answer (score 6):

Como ya se ha dicho, [`preg_match()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php) es la función idónea para este tipo de validaciones.

Este REGEX también funcionaría:

```
/^(\d{8})([A-Z])$/
```

[Esta es la fuente](https://gist.github.com/afgomez/5691823) (en Javascript), pero, podemos adaptarlo a un entorno PHP, incluso mejorarlo. Tiene también un REGEX para el NIE y para el CIF, por si interesa en un futuro.

Algo que debería tenerse en cuenta es **si el usuario escribe la letra en minúscula**. Dos soluciones son posibles:

1. Hacer que el REGEX sea case insensitive (no sensitivo a mayúsculas/minúsculas)
2. Forzar a mayúscula el dato antes de la comparación, lo cual convendría si se interesa guardar los DNI siempre con la letra en mayúscula.

Veamos ejemplos de ambos:

### Solución 1

```
/* 
    Poniendo el pattern para las letras así: [A-Za-z]
    lo hacemos case insensitive 
*/
$dni=!empty($_POST["dni"]) ? $_POST["dni"] : NULL;
$regex="/^(\d{8})([A-Za-z])$/";
if ($dni && preg_match($regex, $dni)) {
    //Usar $dni o lo que sea
} else {
    //Mensaje de error
}
```

Si no sólo se requiere un mensaje informativo y no necesitas bloques para seguir trabajando en cada caso, puedes cambiar el `if ... else` por un ternario:

```
$regex="/^(\d{8})([A-Za-z])$/";
$dni=!empty($_POST["dni"]) ? $_POST["dni"] : NULL;
echo ($dni && preg_match($regex, $dni)) ? "DNI válido" : "DNI inválido";
```

O, si quieres una versión de una sola línea:

```
$regex="/^(\d{8})([A-Za-z])$/";
echo (!empty($_POST["dni"]) && preg_match($regex, $_POST["dni"])) ? "DNI válido" : "DNI inválido";
```

### Solución 2

Si interesa guardar el DNI con la letra en mayúscula, convendría forzar una conversión con [`strtoupper()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtoupper.php).

En este caso el REGEX podría ir así: `/^(\d{8})([A-Z])$/` pero lo dejaremos como case insensitive, por si acaso, así tenemos seguridad en dos niveles:

```
$dni=!empty($_POST["dni"]) ? strtoupper($_POST["dni"]) : NULL;
$regex="/^(\d{8})([A-Za-z])$/";
if ($dni && preg_match($regex, $dni)) {
    //Usar $dni o lo que sea
} else {
    //Mensaje de error
}
```